# Verical centering of the content with Mudblazor

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am using Mudblazor 6.1.7 and .NET 7.

I would like to display my login form in the middle of the window. with this code the content will be centered horizontally:

```
<MudThemeProvider />
<MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Small">
    <MudGrid Justify="Justify.Center">
    <MudItem>
        @Body
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
</MudContainer>
```

Are there any components or CSS classes from Mudblazor to make the content also centered vertically, or do I have to create a custom CSS class for this?

Comment: Vertical center = flexbox

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this

```
<MudGrid Class="d-flex justify-center">
  <MudItem>
        @Body
   </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `align-items: center;` to the `MudGrid` component. To do that you can use the `Style` or `Class` parameters:

```
<MudGrid Justify="Justify.Center" Style="align-items: center;">
    <MudItem>
        @Body
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

or

```
<MudGrid Justify="Justify.Center" Class="align-items-center">
    <MudItem>
        @Body
    </MudItem>
</MudGrid>
```

and define the css class:

```css
.align-items-center {
  align-items: center;
}
```

[Demo](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/cEmdklGdMHdmWrfd)

[`align-items` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

Answer (score 0):

For the vertical centering, your parent component should have some height, not fits the content. MudStack also useful for aligning, but setting height is the key point.